# Error: Unknown column 'activated' in 'where clause'

Tags: sql, xampp

I wanted to login into the bWAPP ...but the login page was not opening ....it showed that there was no database for bWAPP........ SO I created one in phpmyadmin  and added a table named 'users' with 4 columns namely

1. Login
2. Password
3. Name
4. Email address
   Now I am able to access the login page but when I try to log in... it shows me the following error
   Error: Unknown column 'activated' in 'where clause'

Comment: Some part of the login logic is referring to a column you don't have called **activated**. Surely the bWAPP package includes a script or instructions for creating the database? Or maybe this is one of the bugs? I'm not familiar with bWAPP except by name.

Comment: @Don R ... I read the file regarding the bWAPP and got to know that it works on the mySQL data base so I removed the database which I created and redirected the database for bWAPP to mysql and then when I tried to log in again it showed me following error .... ERROR : Table 'mysql.users' doesn't exist....so what I think now is I want to create a user table in the mySQL database but I don't know how to make it in a correct form ....other it will give the Error: unknown column 'activated' in 'where clause'